# "Read-only file system" after flashing it on MacOS

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I formatted my SD card using SD Card Formatter.app. I flashed it with the Raspian buster lite using balenaEtcher.
When I cd into my SD card to create ssh file to enable SSH, it says `touch: ssh: Read-only file system`

Comment: You do not need to format the SD Card. It is also done with flashing it.

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Have you mounted the sd-card?

Comment: No, I have not explicitly mounted the SD card. I can navigate to /Volumes/boot

Comment: ```/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    268.4 MB   disk2s1
   2:                      Linux                         2.0 GB     disk2s2
```